# CKeditor - Font family

Tags: ckeditor

If I have 2 fonts with the same family name - for example Arial Regular and Arial Bold. How can I know what font is being used by default and how can I tell to use Arial Regular for the regular text and Arial Bold for the bold text?

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor uses `<strong>` tags to denote content that was made bold using the editor.*

You can use this to achieve what you want in the editor's content.css by telling it to use a specific font for `<strong>` tags. Pseudocode:

```
body { font-family: "Arial" }
strong { font-family: "Arial Bold"; }
```

> How can I know what font is being used by default

The easiest way is to look in the content.css file, or enter some text into CKEditor and do right-click -> "inspect element" and see which font is being used.

<sub>* = this may not necessarily apply to bold content copy & pasted from somewhere else, say MS Word. But all bets are off with that anyway.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your question! The problem is - the font list is dynamic. So from the beginning I don't know which fonts user will add.